# Subdomain Routing in Sails.js

Tags: node.js, virtualhost, sails.js

I am trying to figure out a way to route subdomains in Sails.js in such a way, that is completely dynamic, the default routing does not seem to allow this.

For example; if a user goes to theirname.example.com, the route would read that as example.com/users/theirname, and any parameters on the subdomain would tag onto the end /user/theirname. I have been searching the web for quite a few hours for some solid information on how to achieve such a thing.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/1297

Comment: Uh oh, it only took @bredikhin 15 minutes! :)

Comment: SO would i need to use this with string manipulation functions and regex's in order to generalize the route and properly execute it ? it will be dynamic, so when a user signs up they automatically have a subdomain. rather than me defining them manually.

Comment: @ScottGress It's probably the same answer you'd post anyways. ;)

Comment: @bredikhin I would have posted the exact same comment. I was just teasing the OP about your superior answer-finding skills :)

Comment: @flaiks Yes, you could make the example more dynamic to handle any domain rather than just the hard-coded ones, but if you want different controllers for the domains you'd still have to create them manually. It doesn't sound like that's what your case calls for, though.

Comment: No, it would be like, for example, facebook, each subdomain leads to a users page, it will be somewhat customized to each user, but that will all be done programmatically. Also, i have seen this answer before but it was only pertaining to specifically defined subdomains.